# State diagram for JK-flip-flop

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, state-machines

I'm trying to create a simple state-diagram for a JK flip-flop, and this is what I've come up with. [image]

I've seen other variants of this diagram, but to me this seems like a correct one if you look at the state table:

[image]

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

The state diagram is correct, but, for completeness, I would put (in the upper circle) Q = 0 *and* /Q = 1, and in the lower circle, Q = 1 *and* /Q = 0.

Why? Because if you want to add the effect of the reset and set entries to the JK FF (which most circuits have), then the extra states (Q = 0 *and* /Q = 0, and both at 1) are possible.

But, if you simple consider the basic JK, then your diagram *is* correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you draw the state diagram right, it does seems to work

but, in my opinion you should add to the diagram the don't-cares, it's make the state diagram more readable.

Comment: I'm not sure that you mean with don't cares in this situation. Could you elaborate?